# Editing "text connection" paths

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that pulls data from multiple CSV files via the "Connections" menu. The problem I'm running into is I need to be able to change the path to the CSV files from within VBA.

After repeated Binging (that's almost a bad word) I came across some solutions, but they involve an SQL connection rather than a text connection. Since the files are CSV, Excel makes it a text connection, and thus there is no ODBC connection string to modify (I get an error when trying to modify it from VBA). I've also dug through the MSDN docs to no avail.

Does anyone know of a way to change a "Text" connection path in Excel, from within VBA?

Also, since I'm on the topic, is it possible to have relative paths to files as opposed to the full file path (such as "\data\some_report.csv" rather than "c:\somedir\data\some_report.csv")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned...

> I came across some solutions, but they involve an SQL connection rather than a text connection.

So use `.TextConnection.Connection` instead of `.ODBCConnection.Connection`  :)

Here is a quick example. Please amend it as applicable.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Conn As Variant
    Dim ConString As String
    Dim oldPath As String, NewPath As String

    NewPath = "C:\MyPath.Csv"

    Set Conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1)

    Debug.Print Conn.TextConnection.Connection
    '==> TEXT;C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Delete Later\Output.csv

    ConString = Conn.TextConnection.Connection

    oldPath = Split(ConString, ";")(1)

    ConString = Replace(ConString, oldPath, NewPath)

    Conn.TextConnection.Connection = ConString
End Sub
```

Comment: I as thinking that this was a [QueryTable.Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837414.aspx) property. The [TextConnection.Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.textconnection.connection.aspx) property doesn't seem to apply to VBA.

Comment: maybe conn.Refresh is needed to update the data immediately :)

Comment: @jeeped the suggested solution works perfectly in my installation, as long as i imported the files as "from text". Might be specific to version (Office15 here)