# Updating "text connection" path using provided string and preserve text to column settings

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with several sheets connected to many external csv files. This has worked fine for now working on my own, but now I'd like to be able to move the Excel file and/or csv files, or hand them off to someone else, and not break the connections.

The method here works for updating the file name based on a provided string:

[Editing "text connection" paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430962/editing-text-connection-paths)

...but it doesn't preserve the text to columns settings after updating the path. Since I'm dealing with csvs, I need the import to come in as comma delimited. Since I'm dealing with a lot of connections in a single file, I'd also like to be able to let the user define a single path somewhere, and have it automatically use that path to find the files.

Comment: What do you mean with connections here? Are you using Jet ADODB to query the CSV files? If so you can define your connection string in code at runtime so would be more than capable of doing your intent. I tend to use `ThisWorkbook.Path` alot so that I can move a project to a differnet folder root and it doesnt break my code. I think including some sample code here would improve your question significantly.

Comment: @nbayly So far I've been going through the wizard and not using VBA. Get External Data/ From Text and then used the wizard to select file and text to column settings.